# Disable PKCS#7 padding on an AES cipher object?

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, aes, pkcs#7

i am programming a fuse file system and i've a poblem.

I am ciphering the data in the disk by using CBC AES. The problem is the padding. It is no problem when the size to cipher is for example 15 bytes because it adds 1 byte extra. The problem is that when i am trying to cipher 4096 bytes it also adds me 16 bytes of padd and it is fail for me. I do not know why it is adding padding because 4096 is multiple of 128 (size aes block). I need to modify my c code for say to openssl that only add padding when it will be neccesary but not always...

I know that if the plaintext is not multiple of 128 it is going to add padding. But why if not? What can i do?

Here my cipher code:

```
    int encrypt_data(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *key,
                unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *ciphertext, int algorithm_pos)
{
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

        int len;

        int ciphertext_len;

        /* Create and initialise the context */
        if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();

        /* Initialise the encryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
         * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
         * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
         * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
         * is 128 bits */
        if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, ciphers[algorithm_pos].algorithm(), NULL, key, iv))
                handleErrors();

        /* Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output.
         * EVP_EncryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
         */
        if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
                handleErrors();
        ciphertext_len = len;

        /* Finalise the encryption. Further ciphertext bytes may be written at
         * this stage.
         */
        if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
        ciphertext_len += len;

        /* Clean up */
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

        return ciphertext_len;
}
```

Comment: CBC mode provides confidentiality only, and you usually must add a MAC to use CBC mode safely. You should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 3):

See [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7). The reason for padding an exact multiple of the block size is there would be no way to tell if there was no padding so padding must either always or never be used. Consider if the data was 4096 bytes and the last byte was 0x01. Looks like one byte of padding but it isn't, it is part of the data.

But you should be using a disk sector encrypting mode such as XTS, XTS is only recommended for full-disk encryption. That is what it was designed for by the IEEE Standard 1619.

See [Explanation of the XTS Encryption Mode](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/102600/5121).

Also NIST: [The XTS-AES Mode for Confidentiality on Storage Devices](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38e.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that when i am trying to cipher 4096 bytes it also adds me 16 bytes of padd and it is fail for me. I do not know why it is adding padding because 4096 is multiple of 128 (size aes block).

As Zaph stated, PKCS#7 padding is being added. The padding is deterministic, so an exact multiple of 16 byts is also padded to ensure removal. Otherwise, how does a generalized algorithm know when (1) plain text ends on a 16-byte boundary, versus (2) plain text *not* ends on a 16-byte boundary and padded?

You can disable the padding behavior on the cipher object with [`EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl.html) and [`EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl.html). `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding` is a macro'd version of `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl`. Here is what it looks like:

```c
int EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *x, int padding);
```

From the man page:

> EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding() enables or disables padding. By default
>   encryption operations are padded using standard block padding and the
>   padding is checked and removed when decrypting. If the pad parameter
>   is zero then no padding is performed, the total amount of data
>   encrypted or decrypted must then be a multiple of the block size or an
>   error will occur.

---

> I know that if the plaintext is not multiple of 128 it is going to add padding. But why if not? What can i do?

Disable padding on your cipher context object. Here's how the library does it:

```
$ grep -IR EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding *
CHANGES:  *) New function EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding() this is used to
apps/enc.c:            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0);
apps/speed.c:                EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(&ctx, 0);
crypto/cms/cms_pwri.c:    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(&kekctx, 0);
crypto/evp/evp.h:int EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *c, int pad);
crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:int EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, int pad)
crypto/evp/evp_test.c:        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(&ctx, 0);
crypto/evp/evp_test.c:        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(&ctx, 0);
```